# Selenium handling html elements inside object tag

Tags: java, selenium

I'm struggling with validating html elements inside html object tag.

Following is my test html (`test1.html`).

```html
<html>
<body>
    <h1>this is test 1</h1>
    <object id='obj1' width="100%" height="200px" data="http://www.w3schools.com/"></object>
    <br>    <br>    <br>    <br>
    <iframe id='ifr1' width="100%" height="200px" src="http://www.w3schools.com/"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

In case of `iframe`, it is easy to handle by using webdriver switchto frame method like following example.

```
@Test
public void testIframe() {
    try {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost/test1.html");

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div")).getText().equals("THE WORLD'S LARGEST WEB DEVELOPER SITE"));

        driver.quit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But in case of object tag, `switchTo` method can't be applied with same way.
I'm curious that Selenium provides this kind of handling.

Does anybody have an idea to solve this problem, or have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SwitchTo api to access object element as well by this way:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("object")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually in WebDriver for frame we use

```
driver.switchTo().frame();
```

for objects we can directly handle or perform operations directly

for example from your code, if i want to take the `value of data attribute`

I used

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//object[@id='obj1']")).getAttribute("data")
```

which will `return` the value `http://www.w3schools.com/`

we can handle it like normal web element , **we no need to use switchTo()**

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm trying to inspect inside html elements which is defined by data attribute. For example, System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//object[@id='obj1']/html/body/div[1]/div")).getText()) ==> this throws "unable to locate element exception"

Comment: @SeonghaHan i guess, you write your xpath wrongly..what text you are tryin to get

Comment: I'm trying to validate some texts in http://www.w3schools.com page, not in test1.html.

Comment: Firebug does not represent xpath for inside page. It displays just object tag itself. In case of google DOM inspector shows full html inside, but did not work like I mentioned above. I guess this is not from wrong xpath expression. I'm suspecting webdriver does not support getting elements html object tag is targeting. But I'm expecting another workaround exists. For the iframe tag, I can do anything using by switchTo frame method. Thanks

Comment: @SeonghaHan Actually the xpath what you are using is in wrong format  "//object[@id='obj1']/html/body/d‌​iv[1]/div"

Comment: I found that JavaScript executor can be applied in this case, but my company policy denies injecting any JavaScript Executor for maintenance issue. I just want to fix this issue using pure WebDriver API supported by Selenium.

Comment: I know my xpath doesn't work, that was just my try. Do you know proper xpath expression for getting elements in http://www.w3schools.com ?

Comment: I already added full html source code (test1.html), If you have your own web server, you can just open test1.html, and you can try to search any html elements in http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: After opening w3schools.com , i want to press Learn HTML tab for that situation xpath is   "//a[contains(text(),'LEARN HTML')]"

Answer (score 1):

I also used something similar to @Deepak_Mahalingam. In case anyone finds his syntax not working. I use chrome and inspect the code to get the xpath.

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gl-consoleTabs-slides"]/div/div/object').get_attribute('data')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and the below solution worked for my project:

1.I wrote a java method to get the URL from the `data` attribute in the `<Object>` tag from source code.
2.Opened the extracted URL in a new tab and performed the testing needed.
3.Switched back to the main tab.

Here the method I used, you can modify this as per your requirement:

```
public void getObjectTagURL(){
   try {
      String pageSource= driver.getPageSource(); 
      int startIndex =str.indexOf("http://www.myURL");         
      int endIndex= str.indexOf("</object>");
      String url= str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);  
   } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);   
     }
```

Hope it helps.